# How do I fix the faded part of an image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image with a faded square. I need the faded square to restore back to its original color which can be seen around the edge of the image. How do I only process the center square of the image to match the edges.

I tried using histogram equalization but with no success as the difference was only enhanced.

Original Image:
[image: Original image]

After histogram equalization:
[image: After histogram equalization]

Comment: we've had this question several times already in the past month. are you all in the same class or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can try applying edge-preserving gaussian filtering instead of Histogram.

For example, you can try bilateral filter or guided filter

There are OpenCV implementations, but I never tried them.

Following MATLAB code demonstrates the filters:

```
I = rgb2gray(im2double(imread('I.jpg')));

G = imguidedfilter(I, 'DegreeOfSmoothing', 0.005);
J = imsharpen(G, 'Amount', 2);

figure;imshow(J)

B = imbilatfilt(I);
K = imsharpen(B, 'Amount', 2);
figure;imshow(K)
```

**If this doesn't seem to work,**

Try this approach, using Histogram:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

# Load in image as grayscale
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg', 0)

plt.hist(image.ravel(), 256, [0,256])
```

The pixels are clustered around the mid range intensities. To increase the contrast of the image, histogram equalization stretches out the intensity values over the whole range to obtain a wider and more uniform distribution. You can do this with the built-in function, `cv2.equalizeHist()`

```
equalize = cv2.equalizeHist(image)
plt.hist(equalize.ravel(), 256, [0,256])
```

The intensity ranges are now evenly distributed. Histogram equalization considers the global contrast of the image and works great when the histogram of the image is confined to a particular region. Here's the result

In some cases where there are intensity variations across a large region, CLAHE (Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization) may be better. CLAHE is implemented in OpenCV as `cv2.createCLAHE()`

```
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE().apply(image)
plt.hist(clahe.ravel(), 256, [0,256])
```

Comment: I used histograms just like the way you suggested, however, the results are seen in the images above. I tried clahe after you suggested but it seems as though histogram equalization do not work on these kind of problems. If there is a way to detect the faded part and maybe use image maths to equalize the faded part with the original it could solve the problem